# Highcharts not diplaying percentage

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to display only percentage in corresponding bit of pie. The charts appears a line between the percentage and the pie.

Comment: please show the more information to us,like that the code snippet you writed,the errors it poped up,..

Comment: what do you mean by _The charts appears a line between the percentage and the pie._  Please explain

Comment: Please post the relevant code. I stopped being psychic at the age of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rehankhalid/nhw9mc3L/)

you need add {point.percentage:.1f} in 'format'

```
format: '{point.name}:{point.percentage:.1f} %'
```

**Update**
For removing lines  use this in dataLabels

```
connectorColor: 'transparent'

dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                connectorColor: 'transparent',
                format: '{point.name}:{point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
```

i have updated the fiddle

Comment: Thanks. But how can i remove the line?

Comment: you mean these lines (screenshot) ? =>  https://www.screencast.com/t/Cu66P89Qe

Comment: i have updated the answer, you can check. need to use connectorColor: 'transparent',

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend

Comment: Also when I have percentages like: 45% and 55% my chart become smaller! How I can keep the size constant?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of connector lines, set `connectorWidth` with 0 value. To show percentages, you need to modify data labels `formatter`. You could also decrease the `distance` between data labels and a pie. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.numberFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/61hbm23h/

Comment: It does not tell me anything. Provide us with an example where this problem occurs.

Comment: I have 2 pie graphs which appears the present and absent staff(red color shows absent staffand blue shows present staff).So I have 2 bit in both graphs. When one of them obtain persentages 66% absent and present 34% this graph become smaller than the other